# Reject numeric values to be indexed for fields with text/keyword data type ( ElaticSearch 6.2.3 )

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-mapping

text or keyword data type allows numeric values to be inserted.

index template is as shown below:

```
{
    "index_patterns" : [ "temp-index" ],
    "mappings": {
        "docs" : {
            "properties": {
                "username" : {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

document inserted :

```
{
    "username" : 10
}
```

as the above document is inserted successfully, is it possible to reject such numeric values for text/keyword datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`coerce`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html) setting but I think it only works vice versa -- i.e. not allowing strings to be indexed as numbers:

```
PUT roddo
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "username": {
        "type": "integer",
        "coerce": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way, attempting

```
POST roddo/_doc
{
  "username": "10"
}
```

will throw an `Integer value passed as String` error.

---

Alternatively, you could extend the username functionality:

```
PUT roddo2
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "username": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "integer": {
            "type": "integer",
            "coerce": true,
            "ignore_malformed": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which is going to attempt to coerce but will not throw an exception when failed.

After syncing your documents you'll be able to find those that **did not** have integer usernames:

```
GET roddo2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "username.integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi joe, i wanted exactly the same thing for text/keywords. coerce is not applicable for text/keyword.